# Tricky Interview question on searching

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I recently heard this question from a friend who was asked this in an interview. He was not able to figure it out and i have not yet found any efficient solution to it either. I hope there is an algorithmist here who can show me a new approach

Question:

Given an array A and a number S', provide an efficient algorithm (nlogn) to find a number K such that if all elements in A greater than K are changed to K, the sum of all elements in the resulting array will be S'.

Example, given `A: [90,30,100,40,20]` and `S' = 210`, `K` will be `60`.

Answer (score 15):

Written in Python, which should be quite readable even if you don't know the language:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

A = [90, 30, 100, 40, 20]
S = 210
K = 60

A    = sorted(A)
prev = 0
sum  = 0

for index, value in enumerate(A):
    # What do we need to set all subsequent values to to get the desired sum?
    solution = (S - sum) / (len(A) - index)

    # That answer can't be too big or too small.
    if prev < solution <= value:
        print solution

    sum += value
    prev = value
```

Result:

```
60
```

Sorting is O(*n* log *n*) and the loop is O(*n*). Combined the algorithm as a whole is therefore O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: you could break out of the loop when the solution is found.

Comment: It can be done in linear time without sorting, so you don't need to use radix sort to get linear time (see my sol'n).

Comment: I don't think you need the variable 'prev' here. As the array is sort, there is no way 'solution' could be smaller than 'prev'.

Answer (score 6):

First sort the list smallest to largest and find how long it is. Then start adding up the numbers one by one. At each step, also find a lower limit on what the sum could be - what the sum of the whole list would be, if all of the rest of the numbers you haven't added in yet are the same as the current number.

At some point this lower limit on the sum will go from being smaller than S', to larger than S', and at that point you can do some arithmetic to determine  what the cutoff should be. eg (C = current sum, L = lower limit on total sum):

```
start
[90 30 100 40 20]
sort
[20 30 40 90 100]
start adding up the sum
C1 = 20
L1 = 20 + 4*20 = 100 < 210

C2 = 20 + 30 = 50
L2 = 50 + 3*30 = 140 < 210

C3 = 50 + 40 = 90
L3 = 90 + 2*40 = 170 < 210

C4 = 90 + 90 = 180
L4 = 180 + 1*90 = 270 > 210 //too big!

S' = C3 + K*2
therefore
K = (S'-C3)/2 = 60
```

Comment: Nice answer. Same solution I came up after reading the question. Not sure if it's optimal, but it seems to be O(NlogN). I wonder if it's solvable w/o sorting the data (as sorting defines the solution Big O in your solution).

Comment: @mazemaster - Heh, I realized I read the question a bit wrong after I wrote up my answer, so I deleted it while I worked on a rewrite. You did not do it. ;-)

Comment: Yup, correct answer, and is O(n log n).  The sorting step takes O(n log n) time, and rest is just O(n).

Comment: @mazemaster - Thanks for your reply. In your solution above can you explain why you multiply K by 2 (S' = C3 + K*2)

Comment: During that interview, my friend was also told to solve the question in O(Logn) if the list is originally sorted, if possible.

Comment: Is this possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, i doubt it. Any algorithm that returns K in O(log n) cannot depend on some of the values in the list, since simply looking at each element takes O(n). Therefore given an an algorithm and a sorted list, you could run the algorithm to determine which elements are looked at, and then change one of the elements that is not looked at. The algorithm will give the same result for both of these lists even though the true answer is differs between the lists.

Comment: O(log n) is do-able if we have the partial sums of the sorted array however.

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished without sorting in O(n) time by using a variation on linear time select as follows (note that the running times of the iterations of the while loop form a geometric series -- the partition subroutine splits a range of an array, from lower to upper, into elements less than or greater than the element of rank mid, and the running time is proportional to the size of the range of the array):

```
foo(x, s) {
  sumBelow = 0;
  lower = 0;
  upper = x.size();
  while (lower + 1 != upper) {
    mid = (upper + lower) / 2;
    partition(x, lower, mid, upper); // O(upper - lower) time
    sumb = 0;
    maxb = 0; // assuming non-negative to avoid use of flags
    for (i = lower; i < mid; i++) {
      sumb += x[i];
      maxb = max(maxb, x[i]);
    }
    if (sumBelow + sumb + maxb * (x.size() - mid) <= s) {
      lower = mid;
      sumBelow += sumb;
    } else {
      upper = mid;
    }
  }
  K = (s - sumBelow) / (x.size() - lower);
  if (K > maxElement(x)) return error();
  else return K;
}
```

Comment: No, I haven't tested it, but if you're a little skeptical you could convert it to the language of your choice and compare with the sorting-based solution on a bunch of random instances. This would be a little nontrivial though, since I didn't give code for the partition subroutine, which is standard but might require a bit of work to implement.

Comment: +1, but maybe just write it as `partition(x, lower, upper)` since I don't think `mid` is actually needed. This will make your point clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like I am late but anyway hope this algorithm makes some sense .

1. First divide S with the array size . You will get 42 .
2. Find how many numbers in the array are greater than 42 , here it is 2 (P) .
3. Add all the numbers less than 42 and find N = 210 - (sum of numbers less than 42) .
4. In the end N/P should give you the perfect answer and it's in O(N) Time complexity and O(1) Space Complexity.

   Find the executing code here : http://ideone.com/MDL3iy

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   class Ideone {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int S = in.nextInt();
   int[] array = {90,30,100,40,20};
   int len = array.length;
   int sAvg = S/len;

   int trackSmallerThanAverage = 0;
   int countMorethanAverage = 0;

   for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
       if(array[i] > sAvg) {
           countMorethanAverage ++;
       } else if (array[i]<sAvg) {
           trackSmallerThanAverage += array[i];
           }

       }

       int finalValue = ( S - trackSmallerThanAverage )/countMorethanAverage;
       System.out.println(finalValue);
       in.close();

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Super algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I am basically doing a binary search for the value of K in the range [0, max(A)]. While this avoids having to sort the array first (thus preserving the original array), it is still O(n*log(k)) where n is the number of elements in A and k is the maximum value in A.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from itertools import imap

def findK(A,S):
    lo,hi=0,max(A)
    while lo<hi:
        mid=(hi+lo+1)>>1
        result=sum(imap(lambda x: x if x<mid else mid,A))
        if result<=S:
            lo=mid
        else:
            hi=mid-1
    return lo

if __name__=='__main__':
    print findK(A=[90,30,100,40,20],S = 210)
```

Answer (score 0):

sort it nlogn

```
int[] sortedArray;
int s;

int sum=0;

for(int i=0; i<sortedArray.length; i++){
  sum = sum + sortedArray[i];

  if((s - sum)/(sortedArray.length - i) < sortedArray[i+1]){
    return (s - sum)/(sortedArray.length - i);
  }
}
```